# Twitter OAUTH returns an empty array

Tags: php, oauth, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am working on twitter authentication, everything seems to work well till i get to `getAccessToken` which returns `Array ( [ ] => )`.

What I have done:

1. First phase:

   ```
   $connection = new TwitterOAuth('xxxxxxxx','xxxxxxxx');

   $temporary_credentials = $connection->getRequestToken('http://example.com/profile.php?passurl=1');

   $redirect_url = $connection->getAuthorizeURL($temporary_credentials);

   $_COOKIE['oauth_token'] = $temporary_credentials['oauth_token'];

   $_COOKIE['oauth_token_secret'] = $temporary_credentials['oauth_token_secret'];

   header("Location: $redirect_url");
   ```
2. second phase (this is where i encounter the problem)

   ```
   $connection =
           new TwitterOAuth(
                   'xxxxxxxxxx',
                   'xxxxxxxxxx',
                   $_COOKIE['oauth_token'],
                   $_COOKIE['oauth_token_secret']
                   ); 
   $token_credentials = $connection->getAccessToken();
   ```

I intend saving the `$token_credentials` values in the database but it returns an empty array: `Array ( [ ] => )`

What am i not getting right?

Comment: please next time try to indent your code before posting it, it was totally unreadable!

Comment: In `twitteroauth.php` add a `var_dump($response);` to the end of the `http` function. This will be the raw response returned from Twitter. Is it an error or a an access token?

Comment: this is what is returned: string(147) "oauth_token=xxxxstringxxxx&oauth_token_secret=xxxxstringxxxx&oauth_callback_confirmed=true"

Comment: @abraham returns: string(147) "oauth_token=xxxxstringxxxx&oauth_token_secret=xxxxstringxxxx&oauth_callback_con‌​firmed=true". thanks

Comment: That is the response to getRequestToken. What about for getAccessToken?

Comment: @abraham getAccessToken returns: string(1) " "

Comment: Can you do a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) of `var_dump($connection);` after `$connection->getAccessToken();`. Be sure to strip oauth secrets.

Comment: It is very odd that it is an empty string as Twitter usually at least returns an error.

Comment: @abraham Link to gist: for var_dump($connection) - https://gist.github.com/2554619 . for $connection->getAccessToken() plus my twitter authorize function - https://gist.github.com/2554656. thank you so much for the assistance

Comment: @abraham please use this for the var_dump($connection): https://gist.github.com/2554701; for $connection->getAccessToken() plus my twitter authorize function - https://gist.github.com/2554656 ... thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you passing the "oauth_verifier" to the getAccessToken method? In the sample code you are giving, you are not doing it. Take a look at this diagram, specially on part D

[image: OAuth Diagram]

I have used twitteroauth in the past and I remember doing it like this. (starting second fase)

```
$twitterOauth = new TwitterOAuth($AppId, $twSecret, $_COOKIE['oauth_token'], $_COOKIE['oauth_token_secret']);
$twToken = $twitterOauth->getAccessToken($_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']);

$newTwitterOauth = new TwitterOAuth($AppId,  $twSecret, $twToken['oauth_token'], $twToken['oauth_token_secret']);
$response  = (array) $newTwitterOauth->get('account/verify_credentials');
var_dump($response);
```

There are a couple of suggestions I would do though:

- Instead of stoing that information in a cookie, I strongly suggest you use sessions to do the job.
- If you insist on using cookies, please use the [setcookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) function.

Comment: yeah, you hit the two issues: 1. i was not setting the cookie the right way. 2. i was not passing the oauth _verifier to getAccessToken.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you getting your TwitterOAuth class from? Is it a standard class? Or you've written it yourself? I would try debugging the class itself and putting more verbose output in the class functions.

Comment: am using this: https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth... please kindly suggest any fix. thank you

Comment: Try submitting a question on github for that project. You might get better responses there, since it's a custom class.

Comment: is there any other available class one can use. I really need to get this working! arghh!!!

Comment: If you're writing a project from scratch I used http://thinphp.com/ and it worked quiet ok for me. Maybe you can extract the OAuthTwitter class from that project

Comment: Please i may not be able to extract the class from thin php framework

Answer (score 0):

why are you using cookies?
using cookies it is a potential risk because are stored on the client side, use SESSION instead

Another question: 
in teh `$redirect_url` if u make a `print_r` of the `$_COOKIE['oauth_token']` and the another one, r empty?

Im asking this because if u disable the cookies by some addon ( like webdeveloper in firefox) or in the browsers config. Maybe u r using empty values on `$_COOKIE['oauth_token']`,
and `$_COOKIE['oauth_token_secret']` .

Comment: i am having issues setting SESSIONS on the site, so temporarily for testing am using COOKIES which actually holds the right values.